# Transform rows with stage changes and dates into "to" and "from"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataset showing the times when a person moves to a new stage:

| Name | Stage | Amount | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Karen | One | $1 | 01/01/21 |
| Karen | Two | $1 | 08/12/21 |
| Karen | Three | $1 | 05/03/22 |
| Jaren | Three | $4 | 02/02/21 |
| Jaren | One | $4 | 07/19/22 |
| Laren | One | $5 | 04/07/21 |
| Laren | Two | $5 | 08/17/22 |

I'm looking to understand the flow of people and amount through the stages (the amounts are constant per person). So I need to transform the dataset into the following table:

| From Stage | To Stage | Amount | Record Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| One | Two | $6 | 2 |
| One | Three | $0 | 0 |
| Two | One | $0 | 0 |
| Two | Three | $1 | 1 |
| Three | One | $4 | 1 |
| Three | Two | $0 | 0 |

I'm looking to sum the amount only by person and take the number of people that moved from each stage to the other (all possibilities).

Comment: Can you explain more about `From Stage` and `To Stage`. I still do not figure out how to get those two columns

Comment: Assume there are 3 stages: One, Two & Three. A person can move from any stage to another. This means there are three ways to move between stages: one-two, one-three, two-one, two-three, three-one, & three-two. The columns are a representation of these possibilities based on the time-  so both Karen and Laren moved from stage one to three means the record count is 2 and the amount is 1+5=6. Please let me know if this makes sense. Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
# Convert to numerical:
df.Amount = df.Amount.str.lstrip('$').astype(int)

# Make Stage Categorical:
df.Stage = df.Stage.astype('category')

# Optional: Make sure Dates are sorted within each group.
# Wasn't needed in your sample data.
# df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
# df = df.sort_values(['Name', 'Date'])

# Find Next Stage for each Stage: 
df['Next_Stage'] = df.groupby('Name')['Stage'].shift(-1)

# Now when we pivot, all categories are represented:
out = (df.pivot_table(index=['Stage', 'Next_Stage'], values='Amount', aggfunc=['sum', 'count'])
         .droplevel(1, 1) # Get rid of "Amount" header.
         .reset_index()   # Reset the Index.
         [lambda x: x['Stage'].ne(x['Next_Stage'])]) # Remove Rows where Stages are the same.
print(out)
```

Output:

```
   Stage Next_Stage  sum  count
1    One      Three    0      0
2    One        Two    6      2
3  Three        One    4      1
5  Three        Two    0      0
6    Two        One    0      0
7    Two      Three    1      1
```

Answer (score 1):

I went on a brute force approach to define the columns 'From Stage' and 'To Stage' using `df[col].shift()`

```
#redefine column as float, thanks @BeRT2me
df['Amount'] = df['Amount'].str[1:].astype('float')

#define new columns
df['From Name'] = df['Name'].shift(1)
df['From Stage'] = df['Stage'].shift(1)
df['To Stage'] = df['Stage']
df.drop(df.index[df['From Name']!=df['Name']], inplace=True)
print(df)

df1 = df.pivot_table(index=['From Stage', 'To Stage'], values='Amount', aggfunc=['sum', 'count'])
print(df1)
```

Output:

```
    Name  Stage  Amount      Date From Name From Stage To Stage
1  Karen    Two     1.0  08/12/21     Karen        One      Two
2  Karen  Three     1.0  05/03/22     Karen        Two    Three
4  Jaren    One     4.0  07/19/22     Jaren      Three      One
6  Laren    Two     5.0  08/17/22     Laren        One      Two

                       sum  count
                    Amount Amount
From Stage To Stage              
One        Two         6.0      2
Three      One         4.0      1
Two        Three       1.0      1
```

Comment: `.apply(lambda x: x[1:])` can be simplified to `.str[1:]`